# Why Quantum Field Theory series expansion is called Asymptotic?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, perturbation-theory, approximations, asymptotics

I once saw the Freeman Dyson's article, referring the Expansion series occurring in Quantum Field Theory is asymptotic in nature;

It will deviate from actual physical phenomena when too many terms are used.

But I could not find formal proof for proving those expansion is asymptotic.

Is it be able to shown in answer of this question? Or is there an accessible source providing formal proof for it? If it is asymptotic, how many loops are known to provide most correct result?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/422448/2451 and links therein.